# How to draw a line to the edge of the screen(browser) in Rapheal js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I would like to draw(animate a line) in Raphael to the edge of the screen/browser from e.g. the x=100, y=100 pixels to the very right edge of the screen.

I know how to do the animation part, I just need to know how can I dynamically find out the rightest coordinates.

How to do such thing without creating a horizontal scroller in browser?

Is this possible in Raphael js or not at all?

My code so far:

```
var paper = Raphael(100, 100, ???, 1);
var lineToEdge = paper.path("M0 0");
lineToEdge.attr(fillerLine);
var anim = Raphael.animation({path: "M0 0L??? 100"}, 500);
lineToEdge.animate(anim.delay(2500));
```

**???** ***- variables that will somehow give me the rightest x position.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript's window.screen object to get this info.

See:  http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

So your code would look like (sorry, haven't tested this myself):

```
var paper = Raphael(100, 100, screen.width, 1);
var lineToEdge = paper.path("M0 0");
lineToEdge.attr(fillerLine);
var anim = Raphael.animation({path: "M0 0L"+screen.width+" 100"}, 500);
lineToEdge.animate(anim.delay(2500));
```